# Как проверить клик в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, click

Я создаю мини игру в Android Studio. При клике View меняет цвет. Как проверить был ли клик на черном цвете. Вот код`

```
  colorView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int[] androidColors = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.androidcolors);
                    int randomAndroidColor = androidColors[new Random().nextInt(androidColors.length)];
                    colorView.setBackgroundColor(randomAndroidColor);
                    int color = Color.BLACK;
                    ColorDrawable targetColor = (ColorDrawable)colorView.getBackground();
                    int color2 = targetColor.getColor();
                    if (color == color2 ){
                        int score = Integer.parseInt(player.getText().toString());
                        score-=10;
                        String s =Integer.toString(score);
                        player.setText(s);
                    }
                    else{
                        int score = Integer.parseInt(player.getText().toString());
                        score++;
                        String s =Integer.toString(score);
                        player.setText(s);
                        player.setText(s);
                    }            
                }

            });
```

Но не работает когда цвет черный без клика снимает очки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как и написал в комментах сними инициализации из `onCLick` чтобы сам не путался и попробуй

```
switch(targetColor.getColor()) {
   case colorBlack:
        score -= 10;
        player.setText(s);
        break;
   default:
        score++;
        player.setText(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ну просто проверить можно логированием

```
private static final String TAG = "someTag";
Log.d(TAG, "Now clicked on "+ color +" screen");
```

и посмотреть результат в Logcat-е.

подробнее можешь прочитать [тут](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat)

Comment: мне нужно чтоб при клике на черный цвет снимались очки

Comment: сейчас посмотрим но позволь дать пару советов инициализируй переменные вне `onClick` лучше всего сделать это в `onCreate`  тогда и не придется инициализировать `score` и `s` дважды и программа будет работать быстрее